# Error when using GMSPlacesClient in swift using Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

Im following the Google API documentation and attempting to find places around the current device. I am trying to use the GMSPlacesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback.

The documentation example is

```
GMSPlacesClient.currentPlaceWithCallback({ (placeLikelihoods: GMSPlaceLikelihoodList,error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("Current Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        for likelihood in placeLikelihoods.likelihoods {
            if let likelihood = likelihood as? GMSPlaceLikelihood {
                let place = likelihood.place
                println("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                println("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                println("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                println("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
            }
        }
    })
```

However it is failing build with error Cannot invoke 'currentPlaceWithCallback' with an argument list of type '((GMSPlaceLikelihoodList, _) -> Void)'

Suggestions please..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the ": GMSPlaceLikelihoodList" after placeLikelihoods and it should work. For all the GMSPlaceClient methods I've worked with, you dont need to include parameter type in the callback

Comment: This is still returning me the error although i removed ": GMSPlaceLikelihoodList". Please suggest anything else. This is not working

Answer (score 0):

**swift 3, xcode 8.1**

here are my code snippets, after adding `GooglePlaces` via CocoaPods,make sure you have declared the let `var placesClient: GMSPlacesClient?` and get the authorization from `CLLocationManager`

```
placesClient?.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("Current Place error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if let placeLicklihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {
        let place = placeLicklihoodList.likelihoods.first?.place
        if let place = place
        {
            print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
            print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
            print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")
        }
    }
})
```

the code works fine, but still showing an error, "The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal error occurred in the Places API library". But at least, it can be built.